# How to fix the windows authentication delay in Production environment for ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, iis, windows-authentication, iis-8

We have deployed the ASP.NET MVC application in Production environment as same set up as Test environment. Test environment is taking 10-20 seconds to authenticate the users through Windows authentication, but in Production, it is taking 60-80 seconds to authenticate the users.

We have added some logs in code and found that after 60-70 seconds only application is started after hitting the URL in browser (code is executed).

Could anyone help us to check and resolve this issue?

To confirm whether Windows authentication is taking time or not, we have added verbose logging to check the execution time of each method.  IIS version is 8.

Windows authentication should not take more time to load the home page.

Home page has no functionality to display or read data from database which has some text box to search.

Comment: Is this only on the first request after starting the app? Or on all requests after it has started? It is normal for the first request to take longer as the app pool starts up.

Comment: This issue is happening for first time request  only. But same configuration and same Server set up is not taking more than 20 seconds in test environment. Production environment is taking more than 70-80 seconds. Is there any way to improve this ?

Comment: It depends what is causing the slowness. But it doesn't necessarily have anything to do with Windows Authentication. For our sites, we have an automated job to push new code in production, and part of that is making a first request to the site so that the first time a real user accesses the site, it responds faster.